# How to create utfgrid tiles from the GeoJson?

Tags: openlayers-3, geojson, geoserver, jts, utfgrids

I have local map tiles, and i also have geometries. (GeoJson get from the geoserver). now I want to create utfgrid from my GeoJson file.
I have been looking for some library that could help me but i could't find good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a recent version (2.9+) of GeoServer you can request UTFGrid directly as a WMS output using `format=application/json;type=utfgrid`. Check your `getCapabilities` response to see if it is available.

See this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186282/display-geoservers-utfgrid-output-in-openlayers-3) for a fuller discussion of how to use the output.

Comment: @HemalGondaliya if the answer works for you, you can accept the answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: I got the Utfgrid  I have many polygon in my layers and I want to retrive Utfgrid for each but it seems geoserver give the response grid as a line, instead of polygon. is there any way to get the Utfgrid as polygon.